# Using 'symlog' removes some plots in the graph as done by 'log'. So how to code it will show all plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem statement saying: Considering 7 algorithms and 23 problems domains, 30 independent simulations has been carried out for each problems. The results of an individual algorithm for 23 different problems are recorded in column format and each row of the .xls file represents independent simulation results. The task is to make a decisive conclusion about 7 different algorithms and their performance w.r.t each problem domains.

So I had to plot **23 plots**, for each problem one plot with values as **7 algorithm .xls files**. Values are very random there -ve , +ve, zero

input file: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cXpNNB6-b2HwWLk04KcZqUDMgLYQ33S8?usp=sharing\](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cXpNNB6-b2HwWLk04KcZqUDMgLYQ33S8?usp=sharing%5C)

My code for the problem is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
sns.set_theme()
sns.color_palette("bright")

directories = [f'alg{i}' for i in range(1, 8)]
Problem = [f'Problem {i}' for i in range(1,24)]
all_data = [0][0]
all_data = [pd.read_excel(f"D:/C++/Programs/Python/Assignment_4/{dir}/alg.xls", header=None) for dir in directories]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)


for j in range(0,23):
    for data_i, dir in zip(all_data, directories):
        plt.bar(dir, data_i[j].mean(),align='center', alpha=0.5)

    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.suptitle(Problem[j])
    plt.show()
```

which does the work but doesn't shows values in negative one:
[image][image]

while using **symlog'** instead of **'log'** shows negative values but also removes some from previous one which was there with **'log'**

[image][image]

So how to code so that it will show both values in the graph with no data removing.

Comment: I think you need to fiddle with `linthresh` — I don't think it's removing the bars, but they have very small y values and are getting squashed to "basically zero" in the linear regime of the symlog function. This would be easier to demonstrate with a simple copy-pasteable example.

Comment: Your bars are extremely short (the small non-zero values you see probably aren't realistic, but floating point accuracy problems).  Anyway, you'll need to set the threshold for the linear range, e.g. `ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthresh=1e-100)`  See also the [symlog demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/symlog_demo.html).